# how to print stars 5 times as a pattern like 1 star and in 2nd line 2 stars likewise in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in vanilla javascript i know how to print stars in a pattern

```
var i,j
for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
  for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
     document.write("*")

  document.write("<br />")
 }
```

How to achieve this in React JS and if possible can we use map function? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an algorithmic question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're asking how you would end up rendering it inside of React. There's several ways you could go about it, but here's a quick example of how I would go about it.

```
const Stars = () => {

  const handleStars = (lim) => {
    let arr = new Array(lim);
    for(let i=0; i<=lim; i++){
      let str = '';
      for(let j=-1; j<=i; j++){
        str += '*';
      }
      arr[i] = str;
    }

    return arr;
  }

  return (
    <div>Here be stars:

      {
        handleStars(5).map( (e, i) => {
          return <p key={i}>{e}</p>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Stars;
```

Comment: i have an another small doubt how can i reach you @hoobs

Comment: @Harvey Sorry I'm not really experienced with using StackOverflow outside of just lurking around. Is there no way to send a direct message? If not, you can just post another comment here. I'll check back and post an answer.

Comment: no there's no way to reach you out in a private way, till i know i have some other doubts so everytime we cant chat this way right? so i asked you

Comment: Sorry @Harvey, but I'm not really comfortable putting my email or whatever on here, and there doesn't seem to be a DM feature on stackoverflow. Can't you put your "doubts" here as a comment?